# How to assign new Id and name to cloned div, finding on base of ID? in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a DIV and it contains two Input Textboxes.

I am trying to clone above div i.e two more textboxes cloned from above div.

But i am facing issues while assigning new ID and Names to clonable input textboxes.

```
<div class="panel" id="MyJuicePanel">
<div class="cloning" id="MyJuicePanel1">
<input type="text" value="" name="juice.apple.poland[0].varietyName" id="juice.apple.poland0.varietyName">
<input type="text" value="" name="juice.apple.sweden[0].varietyName" id="juice.apple.sweden0.varietyName">
```

On creation of new div, Want to replace above ID's from 0 to 1, 2, 3...n

```
newElem.find("#"+InputId).attr('name', InputName_New).val('');
```

**Alternate, which i do not prefer**: If i use Class in input say class="input1", then it is easy assign new ID's; but i do not want to use class in input and want to find, according to ID and change the name to new name and then from new name, i want to change the ID.

Please find fiddle for more clarity: https://jsfiddle.net/vc6zappq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you loop over the old inputs and than when you change this and loop over the new ones you have access to them and you can change the name or id or whatever you want.

```
$(cloneId+" input").each(function(){
```

has to be

```
newElem.find("input").each(function(){
```

and then you can change the inputs attributes

```
$(this).attr("id", InputId_New);
$(this).attr("name", InputName_New);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vc6zappq/8/

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to use data-id and data-type

```js
            var InputId = $(this).attr('data-id')+1;
            var InputType = $(this).attr('data-type');
            var InputName_New = "juice.apple."+InputType+"["+InputId+"].vaietyName";
```

```html
<div class="panel" id="MyJuicePanel">
        <div class="cloning" id="MyJuicePanel1">
            <input type="text" data-id="1" data-type="poland"  value="" name="juice.apple.poland[0].varietyName" id="juice.apple.poland0.varietyName">
            <input type="text" data-id="1" data-type="sweden" value="" name="juice.apple.sweden[0].varietyName" id="juice.apple.sweden0.varietyName">
        </div>
                  <button id="addBut" type="button" >Add It</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice. I would like to try this way :)